# Is the following statement is True/false ? regarding uniform continious

Tags: real-analysis

Is the  following statement  is True/false ?

If a  function $f :(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is uniformly continious ,then we can extend  it to a function $f'$ that  is also uniformly continious on $[a,b]$

My attempt : i thinks  no,  take  $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ on $(0,1)$  but  it not uniformly conitinious on $[0,1]$

Pliz  verified

thanks u

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ is not _uniformly_ continuous on $(0, 1)$. For finite $a, b$ (that is, $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$) the statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ as well, so your example is not good. A counterexample can't work anyway because the statement is true. Let $x_n$ be any sequence of points in $(a,b)$ that converges to $b$. A uniformly continuous function maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, so the sequence $f(x_n)$ is also Cauchy and hence has a limit. And then you can extend by defining $f'(b)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$. I'll leave you to check why this is a continuous extension. After that do the same process with the point $x=a$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1/x $ on $ (0,1) $ is not uniformly continuous

Answer (score 1):

Not a good counter example, this is the for the initial claim If P, then Q. If f(x) is uniformly continous (a,b), then, f'(x) is uniformly continous in [a,b]. You said f(x)=1/x is not uniformly continuous on (0,1). But you have to show if P then Q, not (~P).